# Understanding SQL Server code, in order to translate it

Tags: sql-server, plsql

I have the following SQL Server code, that I need to translate to PL/SQL.

I'm trying to understand what this code does, can someone help me?

--STEP 0a:

```
Declare prior MONDAY and prior SUNDAY
DECLARE @ENDINGSUNDAY DATE
SET @ENDINGSUNDAY = --'2013-06-23' --PUT ENDING DATE FOR WEEK HERE(the sunday ending the week)
--/*
(SELECT MAX(DATE)
FROM DIM.DATE
WHERE DAY_OF_WEEK_DESC LIKE 'SUNDAY' AND DATE <=CAST(GETDATE()) AS DATE))
```

Comment: I am sorry but if even someone explain me what this code is doing then that would be a great help for me.

Comment: I have edited your question, in response to your comment. Hopefully it will now be a little better received. If you disagree with my edit, click on the "edited ... ago" link. That takes you to the edit history where you can roll it back.
It might also help if you add how much you already understand about the code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM DIM.DATE WHERE DAY_OV_WEEK_DESC LIKE 'SUNDAY' AND DATA <= SYSDATE
```

Comment: @ZahoorAlvi - If this answer was useful you should upvote it. If it solved your problem you should accept it.